# Make target substitution

Tags: sed, makefile, subshell

It seems that the subshell does not retrieve the result of "$@", so there is nothing to do substitution on.

```
%_bust.css: %.css
    @echo $(echo $@ | sed s/_bust/$(BUSTER)/g)
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `$()` with ``. The former is GNU make variable expansion.

Comment: Or double any dollar sign you want to expose to the shell

Answer (score 1):

You've made it unnecessarily complicated. You don't need a nested `echo`.

```
%_bust.css: %.css
    @echo $@ | sed s/_bust/$(BUSTER)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `make`'s text subsitution mechanisms.

```
@echo $*$(BUSTER).css
@echo $(subst _bust,$(BUSTER),$@)
```

The latter is specific to GNU Make, and less precise and elegant in this particular case.